# How to find identical file names in a folder and then move duplicates to a different folder in Python?

Tags: python

I currently have .jpg and .txt files in a single folder. Some of them have identical names and others are just .txt and .jpg files that don't have matching names. Duplicates are basically a .jpg and .txt file that have the same name disregarding file extensions. Now, I need to move all these duplicates to a single folder but I can't figure out how.

I have this current code but it doesn't move anything:

```
import os
import glob
import shutil

images = glob.glob('C:/Users/b/Images')

labels = glob.glob('C:/Users/b/Labels')

if os.name == 'nt':
    separator = '\\'
else:
    separator = '/'
duplicates =[]
for txt in labels:
    # [-1] takes the last part of the path
    # .strip removes .TXT from the file name
    txt_name = txt.split(separator)[-1].strip('.txt')
    for  wav in images:
        wav_name = wav.split(separator)[-1].strip('.WAV')
        wav_path = wav.strip(txt_name + '.WAV')
        # Check if the wav_name and txt_name are the same.
        # There is no check for case.
        if wav_name == txt_name:
            duplicates.append(wav)
            duplicates.append(txt)
for x in duplicates:
    shutil.move(x , 'C:/Users/b/All')
```

Comment: Your message says ".jpg" and ".txt", but your code is dealing with ".WAV".  Do you need to change the description?

Comment: And, by the way. `os.sep` will give you the `separator` value without a need for conditional code.

Comment: and i don't think you need "glob"

Comment: `os.path.basename()` is a better way to get just the filename

Comment: Also, `strip('.txt')` isn't doing what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code that solves the problem you originally described.  That is, if there is a `jpg` in the `Images` directory that has a corresponding `txt` file in the `Labels` directory, then both files are moved to the `All` directory.  If that's not what you wanted, then you need to post a different question.

```
import os

imagepath = 'C:/Users/b/Images'
labelpath = 'C:/Users/b/Labels'
bothpath = 'C:/Users/b/All'

images = os.listdir(imagepath)
labels = os.listdir(labelpath)

imagenames = set(os.path.splitext(k)[0] for k in images if k[-4:]=='.jpg')
labelnames = set(os.path.splitext(k)[0] for k in labels if k[-4:]=='.txt')

for x in imagenames.intersection(labelnames):
    os.rename( imagepath + os.sep + x + '.jpg', bothpath )
    os.rename( labelpath + os.sep + x + '.txt', bothpath )
```

Comment: instead of k[-4:]==".jpg" you can use k.endswith(".jpg")

Comment: @Tim Roberts I used the code you sent but it throws me this error:
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists:

Comment: That can only happen if either (a) the "All" directory did not exist before starting, or (b) the "All" directory exists was not empty.  Make sure "All" exists and is empty before starting.